# Tables converted from markdown to pdf via pandoc puts an unnecessary pagebreak before them

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking, pandoc, markdown

I have a project that converts Markdown files into PDF, using `pandoc` and a LaTeX PDF template.

I'm having a strange issue with the tables. For very few cases (something like 2 in 200 documents), the table is getting inserted after a page break. I'm not sure if it's a page break or not since I basically have very few experience in LaTeX, but it seems like that.

This is one of the Markdown files that I'm converting:

```
... More stuff above

Lorem

- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.

# LOREM IPSUM

## Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.

| Column 1                                       | Column 2                                                                    |
| ---------------------------------------------- | --------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text               | Lorem Ipsum                                                                 |
| Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the        | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  |

## Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

... More stuff below
```

My `pandoc` command is something like this (it gets executed with Powershell, that's what the variables with dollar signs are about):

```
pandoc  --metadata=title:"asasas" `
        --resource-path="$markdownPath" `
        --template="$pdfTemplatePath" `
        --fail-if-warnings `
        --variable numbersections="true" `
        --variable mainfont="Arial" `
        --variable sansfont="Helvetica" `
        --variable monofont="Courier" `
        --variable fontsize=12pt `
        --variable version=2.0 `
        --variable geometry="left=20mm, top=10mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm" `
        --variable toc-own-page="true" `
        --toc `
        --toc-depth=5 `
        --lua-filter="version_table.lua" `
        --variable titlepage="true" `
        --variable logo="PDF/logo.eps" `
        --columns=50 `
        -f markdown-implicit_figures+escaped_line_breaks+raw_tex `
        -t latex `
        -s `
        -o "$outputFileName" `
        "$tempFileName"
```

The PDF template I'm using is very similar to [pandoc-latex-template](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/blob/master/eisvogel.tex), probably built on top of it.

When I run `pandoc` command, this is what the output looks like for the table:

[image]

Any idea what the problem could be? Anything I should try, that could help?

This is the part of the generated tex file for the screenshot above

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*,table}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
,tablecaptionabove
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  % \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmainfont[]{Arial}
  \setsansfont[]{Helvetica}
  \setmonofont[]{Courier}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{default-linkcolor}{HTML}{A50000}
\definecolor{default-filecolor}{HTML}{A50000}
\definecolor{default-citecolor}{HTML}{4077C0}
\definecolor{default-urlcolor}{HTML}{4077C0}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={asasas},
  hidelinks,
  breaklinks=true,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc with the Eisvogel template}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,includehead=true,includefoot=true,centering,left=20mm, top=10mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleWidthIfNeeded{%
 \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\def\ScaleHeightIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@height>0.9\textheight
    0.9\textheight
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\ScaleWidthIfNeeded,height=\ScaleHeightIfNeeded,keepaspectratio}%
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}


\title{asasas}
\date{}


\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,main=english]{babel}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{english}
\fi

\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{multicol}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\definecolor{caption-color}{HTML}{777777}
\usepackage[font={stretch=1.2}, textfont={color=caption-color}, position=top, skip=4mm, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setcapindent{0em}

\definecolor{blockquote-border}{RGB}{221,221,221}
\definecolor{blockquote-text}{RGB}{119,119,119}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[rightline=false,bottomline=false,topline=false,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=blockquote-border,skipabove=\parskip]{customblockquote}
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{customblockquote}\list{}{\rightmargin=0em\leftmargin=0em}%
\item\relax\color{blockquote-text}\ignorespaces}{\unskip\unskip\endlist\end{customblockquote}}

\definecolor{heading-color}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{heading-color}}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{asasas}
\author{}

% tables
\definecolor{table-row-color}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\definecolor{table-rule-color}{HTML}{999999}

\arrayrulecolor{table-rule-color}     % color of \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.3ex}      % thickness of \toprule, \bottomrule
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}     % spacing (padding)

\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{
\rowcolors{3}{}{table-row-color!100}  % row color
\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable
\global\rownum=0\relax}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{eisvogel-header-footer}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \lhead[]{asasas}
  \chead[]{}
  \rhead[asasas]{}
  \lfoot{{Version: 2}{, effective date: 01-Sep-2020}}
  \cfoot[]{}
  \rfoot{{\thepage} of \pageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{eisvogel-header-footer}

\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
  \renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{table-rule-color}
\restoregeometry

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
}

\hypertarget{process-description}{%
\section{LOREM IPSUM}\label{process-description}}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy text ever since the
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
also the leap into electronic typesetting.

\hypertarget{objective-and-benefits}{%
\section{OBJECTIVE AND
BENEFITS}\label{objective-and-benefits}}

\hypertarget{objective}{%
\subsection{Objective}\label{objective}}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard

\hypertarget{benefits}{%
\subsection{Benefits}\label{benefits}}

\begin{itemize}
\item
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry.
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry.
\end{itemize}

\hypertarget{definition}{%
\section{DEFINITION}\label{definition}}

Lorem Ipsum

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry.
\end{itemize}

Lorem Ipsum

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy text ever since the
1500s, when an unknown printer took
\end{itemize}

Lorem Ipsum

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy 
\end{itemize}

Lorem Ipsum

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy text
\end{itemize}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is 
\end{itemize}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is 
\end{itemize}

\hypertarget{roles-responsibilities}{%
\section{LOREM IPSUM}\label{roles-responsibilities}}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
  the industry's standard dummy text ever since
  the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
  the industry's standard dummy text ever since
  the 1500s.
\end{itemize}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lore
\end{itemize}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry.
\end{itemize}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
  the industry's standard dummy text ever since
  the 1500s.
\end{itemize}

Lorem

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
  the industry's standard dummy text ever since
  the 1500s.
\end{itemize}

\hypertarget{lorem-ipsum}{%
\section{LOREM IPSUM}\label{lorem-ipsum}}

\hypertarget{lorem-ipsum-is-simply-dummy}{%
\subsection{Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy}\label{lorem-ipsum-is-simply-dummy}}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy text ever since the
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
also the leap into electronic typesetting.

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.36\columnwidth}\raggedright
Column 1\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.58\columnwidth}\raggedright
Column 2\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.58\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lorem Ipsum\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the\strut
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.58\columnwidth}\raggedright
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting industry.\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show the latex code that corresponds to the screenshot.

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{memoir}\usepackage{longtable}\usepackage{hyperref}` in order to make your code fragment compilable, I end up with the following output https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KDY5.png that does not show the pagebreak before the table that you get. If I add some space above the `itemize` environment, I end up with https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLIZr.png, which is the desired output and still does not exhibit the unwanted pagebreak. Therefore, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: I edited the latex code and added one that will give an output like the one in the screenshot. Although it's quite long and the actual code was even longer and this is the best I could do to minimize it...

Comment: Commenting lines 25 and 26 ( I not have the Helvetica and Courier fonts) the table is just after the last paragraph with xelatex or lualatex in TeXlive 2019. It seems that pdflatex failed because think that last paragraph will end in page 3, so the table must be in next page. The problem is solved with  more flefibility of  `\parskip` (enough change `6pt  2pt minus 1pt`  to  `6pt plus 2pt minus 1.5pt`) so the last paragraph really fit on page 3, or alternatively add a few  words before, so latex will notice that paragraph will end really in the page 4.